# Will Boruto be able to awaken Byakugan?

Tags: naruto, naruto-gaiden

As Himawari was able to awaken Byakugan, is it possible that Boruto will also be able to use it?

I am in doubt because, if we take the Uchiha family as an example, then every member of their family has the ability to use Sharingan. I would guess this also applies to the Byakugan users.

Sasuke's child Sarada also awakened her Sharingan even though Sakura was not a Sharingan user.

So in that case, is it possible that Boruto will be able to use the Byakugan in the future? If not, then does it have something to do with genes?

Comment: Yes, it does have to do with genes. Visual techniques such as the Sharingan and Byakugan are passed down genetically.

Comment: First off, no one except Kishi sensei knows what it's going to be for Boruto and Borutoverse. That said, we can only guess what's going to happen. Secondly, since this is the *Naruto* series, IMO, it would be highly unlikely that Boruto would gain the Byakugan. Because that would make him kind of excess powered.

Comment: I think now even Boruto possesses a Byakugan. (Boruto: Naruto next generations)

Comment: @SahanDeSilva We know Boruto possesses something, but we don't yet know what it is. Its not an ordinary Byakugan. The black sclera and cyan Iris with no veins around the eye are not traits of a Byakugan. No one else having ever seen it also is suspicious, though it could just be a lot of coincidences that prevent anyone from seeing his eye.

Comment: @Ryan I watched the last episode of Boruto. It seems like Boruto possesses something similar to 'Tenseigan'. I wonder if it could happen.. (Still not confirmed though)

Comment: Yea, it is similar to that but still the powers of that eye is not confirmed. Never saw this coming that Boruto series will also come. Maybe the answer for this question will come later in much detail which might tell us more about the powers of Boruto eyes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From trivia [here](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Byakugan#Trivia), it is stated that Masashi Khisimoto forgot to give Byakugan to Boruto and Himawari.

> Boruto and Himawari Uzumaki, despite being children of Hinata Hyūga,
>   do not have the characteristic white eyes inherited by Hyūga
>   descendants.  According to Masashi Kishimoto, he simply forgot to give
>   it to them.

Later he corrected this. But so far, only Himawari has Byakugan.

> Kishimoto later corrected his mistake for Himawari by giving her the
>   Byakugan in the Zai no Sho's special chapter The Day Naruto Became
>   Hokage.  While activated, her eyes take on the normal characteristics
>   of the dōjutsu. When not in use, she has her original blue eyes.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so if any of you have been watching Boruto Next Generations, you already know that Boruto has the Byakugan, since when he's fighting with Kawaki in episode 1, he uses it. Now it's a different thing that he might have it implanted, but when it flashbacks to his academy days, he has the byakugan shadow already, since it has appeared numerous times, first with Denki, then with Metal Lee. So yes, I think the answer is, he will get byakugan, whether just a shadow or implanted.

Comment: that is not Byakugan. that is described to be an unawakened form of Tenseigan

Answer (score 0):

The eye that Boruto has is clearly not a Byakugan, and everyone can agree, what I find it most likely is a new Dojutsu, no one from the Byakugan family ever married someone with as much chakra as Naruto has, unless you count the grand-son of Kaguya (the dude inside the moon) which already had the Byakugan with an extreme chakra source.

Another option would be the mix of the byakugan with a descendant of the sage of the six paths, but this is denied by the fact that Kaguya never had an eye like that manifested, while she is the original blood of any jutsu, as the creator of the series just said that he forgot to give them Byakugans he may have thought to give Boruto something different, Naruto isn't part of the byakugan bloodline so off-springs that don't have the byakugan are totally possible, the "theory" I like the most is the mix between the Uzumaki genes (the Uzumaki clan) with the Byakugan and the blood of the sage of the six paths, there is no recorded or shown eyes like Boruto's, so a bit of diversity could've been expected from the creator.

Although this looks like a continuation of the *Naruto* series, it's not really. If you're someone that never watched *Naruto* you can live happily ever after and have no need to watch it to watch the *Boruto* series, and even if this was the Byakugan that Boruto inherited it would most likely wouldn't make him have excessive power, he is Naruto's son, not Naruto himself, so he doesn't have the nine tails, and for sure not that much chakra as he has.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think think it's likely that boruto will get the byakugan because as you can see in the manga and the anime that he has a new dōjutsu be as in the anime he could see chakra points but he could also open a portal with his new dōjutsu and the byakugan can see chakra points and the rinnegan can open portals so I say borutos prowess is stronger and better than a byakugan and sharingan so it's unlikely from him to have two dōjutsu

Answer (score -2):

Boruto cannot use the byakugan in the anime Boruto Next Generations he has what is called Dōjutsu and its only in his right eye. He may obtain it later but seeing as the byakugan is typically in bothe eyes, Dōjutsu is in only one

Comment: The Byakugan is Dōjutsu, an Eye Technique. saying that Boruto don't have the byakugan because he has Dōjutsu in general is very inaccurate because his mother Hinata has Dōjutsu too and if Boruto was to the Byakugan it would be from his mother

Answer (score -2):

I think being the Naruto series wanting to give Boruto something special, his eye may have been somewhat an evolved type of Byakugan. Being a son of Naruto, someone who has ninetails inside of him that made him special. I think same goes to Boruto.